# Mysql Trigger to find the highest number

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have a table (name: numbers) with the following data:

```
|number a | number b|

|   1     |    2    |
|   0     |    4    |
|   0     |    0    |
|   3     |    5    |
```

I need help creating a trigger that will find the Max value in each row and update another table (name = 'results') with the amount of Max in 'number a' and the amount of Max in 'number b', and also the number of equal values for each row:

```
| a wins | b wins | Draw |

|   0    |   3    |   1  |
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you have tried so far then we can help you figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to calculate expected result:

```
select sum(a) as 'a wins', sum(b) as 'b wins', sum(c) as 'draws'
from (
select 
 if(numbera > numberb , 1, 0) a,
 if(numberb > numbera , 1, 0) b,
 if(numbera = numberb , 1, 0) c
 from numbers) results
```

You can embed this query into trigger and wrap it with an insert query into another table. Here is the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4773a/7/0)**

Comment: I believe he is looking for a `TRIGGER`

Comment: That's what the answer states. OP can use this query in trigger and perform the required insert.